# Having a default Item in dropdown using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have this html which works very well. My topicId displays from 0 to 7 and 0 is the first item.
However nothing is displayed as the default in my dropdown when the page loads until I click the dropdown.

I will like the first item to be displayed as the default. How can I achieve this please?

```
        <div class="selectTopic">
            <select id="cTopic" name="cTopic" ng-model="selectedValue">
                <option ng-repeat="x in cuc.getData" value="{{x.topicId}}"> {{x.topicDescription}}</option> 
            </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: Try to set your model (selectedValue) to the first item in your option's ng-repeat collection.

Comment: How ? Do you have a code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ngOptions instead. Then init the model via the controller to the default value:

```
<select id="cTopic" name="cTopic" ng-model="selectedValue" 
    ng-options="item.topicId as item.topicDescription for item in cuc.getData">
</select>
```

And in controller:

```
$scope.selectedValue = "topicId1";
```

See example:

```js
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);

app.controller("testCtrl", function ($scope) {
 
  $scope.selectedValue = "topicId1";
  $scope.items = [
    {
      topicId : "topicId1",
      topicDescription :"topicDescription1"
    },
    {
      topicId : "topicId2",
      topicDescription : "topicDescription2"
    },
    {
      topicId : "topicId3",
      topicDescription  : "topicDescription3"
    }
  ];
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div class="selectTopic">
        <select id="cTopic" name="cTopic" ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="item.topicId as item.topicDescription for item in items">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use ng-selected: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

```
 <div class="selectTopic">
    <select id="cTopic" name="cTopic" ng-model="selectedValue">
        <option ng-repeat="x in cuc.getData" value="{{x.topicId}}" 
            ng-selected="selectedValue === x.topicId"> 
            {{x.topicDescription}}
        </option> 
    </select>
 </div>
```

However, if you are using plain html, AngularJS has more efficient ways to create dropdowns, see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 0):

The suggested answer will work too, however an alternative that I tend to use is this:

```
<div class="selectTopic">
<select id="cTopic" name="cTopic" ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="x.topicId as x.topicDescription for x in cuc.getData">
    <option value="">Select One ...</option> 
</select>
```

Angular has to start with some value for un-initialized selects, so providing a blank option in the html safely initializes the select without making assumptions on behalf of your users.

Comment: Am working on an application that will be in different languages so I cant have "Select One" in code. Everything is coming from the database

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? the value that will be stored in the model is an empty string (if you don't select something else).

Comment: I tried it and no luck. All other items in the dropdown are not displaying again just the first item is displaying. Select One ..

Comment: oh i missed some stuff in the ng-options, let me edit